# How to disable a parameter based on the value of another parameter?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I would like to hide or set to read only a parameter based on the value of another parameter, for example, let's say that I have 3 parameters:

- ApplcationName
- Enable_Nexus which is choice: true or false
- Zip which is a local upload 
  I would like to hide the second parameter when the first one is true

Can someone helps?

Best regards,
Salhi